# Use regex to extract link

Tags: php, regex

I have particular lines that will appear in a post from a textarea and I need to extract them and convert them to a link. The php code i had from a previous example works ok if the id is just a digit, but I now need it to work for a url that could contain letters, numbers, dashes and forward slashed

```
$pattern = '/@\[([^\]]+)\]\(id:(\d+)\)/';
$replacement = '<a href="link/$2">$1</a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

The pattern matches everything except the url. How do I change \d+ to what I need. I thought \w might have worked but it doesnt.

`@[Lucy Lawless](id:residential-lettings/landlords/view/landlord/161)` will become `<a href="residential-lettings/landlords/view/landlord/161">Lucy Lawless</a>`

`@[200 Daly Park ](id:residential-lettings/properties/view/property/257)` will become `<a href="residential-lettings/properties/view/property/257">200 Daly Park</a>`

`@[Courrrty](id:residential-lettings/supplier/view/supplier/7)` will become `<a href="residential-lettings/supplier/view/supplier/7">Courrrty</a>`

Comment: `.` matches any character. `\d` matches only digits, `\w` matches any letter, number or underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex like below,

```
@\[([^\[\]]+)\]\(id:([^()]*)\)
```

and then replace the match with `<a href="$2">$1</a>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/11)

`[^()]*` Matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.

```
$pattern = '~@\[([^\[\]]+)\]\(id:([^()]*)\)~';
$replacement = '<a href="$2">$1</a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have changed my pattern to which works now $pattern = '/@\[([^\]]+)\]\(id:([^()]*)\)/';

Answer (score 0):

```
\[([^\]]+)\]\(id:(.*?\d+)\)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `<a href="link/$2">$1</a>`.

Just changed `\d+` to `.*?\d+` so that it includes all upto `\d+`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/12

```
$re = "/\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\(id:(.*?\\d+)\\)/m";
$str = "[Lucy Lawless](id:residential-lettings/landlords/view/landlord/161)\n[200 Daly Park ](id:residential-lettings/properties/view/property/257)";
$subst = "<a href=\"link/$2\">$1</a>";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```